# How to connect FFmpeg with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ffmpeg

I want to know how can I connect FFmpeg with my codeigniter project. I know that I have to put the exe file in our site root folder but I don't how to connect it

Comment: Care to [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+ffmpeg&oq=php+ffmpeg&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.6423j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to install ffmpeg into codeigniter:

1. Download ffmpeg.exe (www.ffmpeg.org)
2. Unpack the downloaded zip file. There will be three files inside: ffmpeg.exe, ffplay.exe, and pthreadGC2.dll
3. download also ffprobe.exe
4. copy above those files
5. paste into your local codeigniter project root path.
   like your project name "project1".
   into "project1" just paste all.
6. restart your local server.

   that's all, thanxxx... :)

Comment: Thanks, @Faridul Khan. It is working on my local server